# Is Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller secure?

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser, google-chrome-extensions

Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller, which is an extension for Chrome browser really seems a nice product.

But, on the security side, "it can access your data on all websites", this is the official statement about permissions that this extension enjoys. What does this actually mean? Can this extension access my saved passwords? Is accessing my data actually necessary for products like this to function?

[image]

[I am using Chrome browser on OS X Mavericks]

Answer (score 1):

At the detail-tab of this extension, they explain this message:

> - This extension does not access any of your history database. The alert comes from use of tabs API that is for applying changes on
>     configuration tab immediately to all existing tabs.  Read this page
>     for details. 
>     http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html

[Source](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-wheel-smooth-scr/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb):

Comment: The official statement just says "it can access your data on all websites", it should mean it would access all data.

Comment: Describing a possible risk is the best they can do in an automatic description. Like the difference between "children may choke on peanuts" and "children definitely will choke on these peanuts".